# Evaluate: $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}~dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, integration

> How can I evaluate: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}~dx$$

How I proceed:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}~dx=2\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{h})^2}~dx=2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\arctan\frac{1}{h}$$ 
Then how can I prooceed. Please help. Thank in advance.

Comment: Why can't you go on by yourself :-)? You have almost finished: there is no indeterminate form.

Comment: you put extra ${1 \over h}$ in the last

Comment: @experimentX: I forgot that in previous expresion

Comment: Last expression will be $2\lim_{h \to 0}\arctan\frac{1}{h}$.I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\arctan x=\frac{\pi}2$$ while
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\arctan x=-\frac{\pi}2$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac1h\arctan\frac{1}{h}=\lim_{y \to +\infty}y\arctan y=(+\infty)\frac\pi 2=+\infty$$ 
while
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac1h\arctan\frac{1}{h}=\lim_{y \to -\infty}y\arctan y=(-\infty)\frac{-\pi} 2=+\infty$$ 
The required limit is
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac1h\arctan\frac{1}{h}=+\infty$$

Comment: If I take $y=\frac{1}{h}$ then I get $\lim_{y \to \infty}y \arctan y$.What I can do with this **y**.

Comment: @Argha As you said, you are looking for the limit of $\arctan\frac1h$ and not $\frac1h\arctan\frac1h$

Comment: No,I want $\frac{1}{h}\arctan \frac{1}{h}$ not $\arctan \frac{1}{h}$

Comment: So, I conclude limit exists and equal to $+\infty$

Comment: now I understand the problem. Thank you

Comment: @Argha Should I add more detail in my answer?

Comment: No.It's enough.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}~dx=2\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{h})^2}~dx=2\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{0}^{1/h}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{h})^2}~d\left({x\over h}\right) $$
$$ 2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \arctan(1/x) = \pi \text{ as stated above.}$$

Comment: why don't you change limit of integration $(0,1)$ to $(0,1/h)$

Comment: yeah!! sorry forgot about that!!

Comment: $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{0}^{1/h}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{h})^2}~d\left({x\over h}\right)  = \lim_{h \to 0} \arctan (1/h) - \arctan 0$ which is same

Comment: this seems to work http://tinyurl.com/cnvd4wg

Comment: I delete my comment.You are right.

Comment: Why change the upper limit in the integral? There's no substitution there!